# App goes to "allow dropbox" screen instead of onCreate

Tags: android, dropbox

### Solved

Completely reinstalling the app was apparently not enough. I restarted my phone once and the app is back to where it was before this happened.

### Original post

I'm making this app that integrates with dropbox and I've recently run in to some problems.

For a couple of months it worked as it should have. It asked for permission to use the logged in dropbox account on the phone when the app was first installed and after that all dropbox related stuff was made in the background as it was supposed to.

Recently I made a small change in my code which made the app go completely haywire and it just keep reloading the "allow dropbox" screen and you could not interact with the app. So naturally I reverted the change to how it was before but the problems didn't go away.

### The Problem

Whenever I start the app it goes directly to the "allow dropbox" screen and when I press allow or deny it closes the app and goes back to my homescreen.

I have commented out every line of code related to dropbox, completely removed and reinstalled the app on my phone, and done a lot of cleans and rebuilds and all that in Android Studio but the problem is still there.

So now when I start the app it goes to the "allow dropbox" screen but since all that code is commented out it just says that the app is not correctly set up and all I can do is close it again.

The manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.korpasjaervii.timereporter.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.korpasjaervii.timereporter.CompilationActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.korpasjaervii.timereporter.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.korpasjaervii.timereporter.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.korpasjaervii.timereporter.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName="com.korpasjaervii.timereporter.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.korpasjaervii.timereporter.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <!--<activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="db-rt97pzc7umt2krp" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>-->
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
</application>
```

MainActivity's onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

This is obviously not the actual onCreate but I reduced it to this and the problem is still there.

I should also say that logcat doesn't even register that my app has been opened.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: I added the manifest and the onCreate method of my MainActivity in my question

Comment: Oh, the good-ol solution of "did you try restarting it"... You can post an answer below and accept it to let others know that was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently something happening when you restart your phone that doesn't happen when you completely reinstall the app. Because I've reinstalled it several times with no change but restarting the phone once solved it...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what SDK version your app is targeting, but with Android 6.0 (aka 23), the permissions model has changed and your code must be adapted to ask for permissions when it needs them and fail gracefully if the user doesn't give you the requested permission.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Comment: Permissions are not the problem. I doesn't work with the new permission system and before it went haywire it worked just fine with the old permission system.

According to logcat my app doesn't even start.